# When does authentic pride become hubris pride?

Tags: emotion, self

There are two kinds of pride: hubris pride and authentic pride¹. "Authentic pride is tied to adaptive achievement and goal engagement, whereas hubristic pride is tied to extrinsic values of public recognition and social dominance"². I wonder how and when authentic pride becomes hubris pride?

I think the two are interrelated because both kinds of pride have the same gesture, and seems to create the same social impact in short term. I don't think there is a gray area between them, but I think they can "swap" to each other relatively fast, and can happen back and forth.

The images below show some gestures of pride:

[image]
[image]

(Since both types of pride display the same gesture, so I guess there is no way to point to an image and say "this is hubris pride" and to another "that is authentic pride". The way to differentiate them, I think, largely relies on the context, not on body gesture.)

<sub>¹ David DeSteno, [Pride can be a virtue, but it needs to be the right kind of pride](https://ideas.ted.com/pride-can-be-a-virtue-but-it-needs-to-be-the-right-kind-of-pride/), TED Ideas

² Carver and Johnson, [Authentic and Hubristic Pride: Differential Relations to Aspects of Goal Regulation, Affect, and Self-Control](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3137237/), Journal of Research in Personality</sub>